# Is there a BASH equivalent of zsh's $VENDOR variable?

Tags: bash, zsh

In ZSH, I can get vendor using

```
zsh$ echo $VENDOR

apple
```

However, it doesn't seem to be available in BASH (or sh).  Is there anything equivalent in BASH? Or is there a quick way to get something similar?   My guess is to use `$MACHTYPE` but it has extraneous values (ie $HOSTTYPE, $OSTYPE)

```
bash$ echo $MACHTYPE

x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

- I only need `redhat` or `apple`, etc.

Comment: `uname` can be used as alternative. Or add environment variable in `.bashrc`, like this `export ARCH=$(uname -m)`.

Comment: It looks like there's no equivalent in BASH.  In zsh's source code [zsh/config.sub](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/19390a1ba8dc983b0a1379058e90cd51ce156815/config.sub) , the `$vendor` is created/generated by parsing and decoding from local machine's info.